# sending python c_types structure through network

Tags: python, c++, networking

I have a structure declared as c_types

```
 class MyMessage(Structure):
   __fields__ = [ ("name",c_char * 32), ("id", c_int) ]
```

I want to send this data to my c++ client through UDP using the following pseudocode

```
 myMessage = MyMessage()
 socket.sendto( *myMessage*, host, port)
```

In my C++ I usually call hton on each field then write the structure to a char buffer. How do I do this in python? I see people using struct.pack, is that the right way? Should I deal with hton when I format using struct.pack?

Comment: all you send over a network is bytes ... you have to tell whatever is on the other end how to reassemble the data ... I would just send ascii probably if it was me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use `struct.pack`.  You can specify byte order when writing the pack format string.  To format it for `hton` you can use the `>` symbol.  See the struct docs on [byte order and alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-alignment)

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack(">L", 1)    # big endian
'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> struct.pack("L", 1)
'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```